# singular matrix in python implementation of newton-raphson method

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, numerical-methods, newtons-method

I've written a code in python which implements the Newton-Raphson method to solve multiple nonlinear equations.

The specific question I've taken is from *Mark Newman's - Computational Physics, exercise 6.17 Nonlinear circuits*

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import solve, norm
from math import e

#DATA
vp= 5. #V_plus in volts
r1, r2, r3, r4 = 1., 4., 3., 2. #k-ohm resistances
i = 3. #A constant originally in nA
vt = 0.05 #V_t in volts

def f(x):
'''
evaluates f(x) for where x is a 2-dim vector of voltage v1 and v2
'''
    v1, v2 = x[0], x[1]
    y = np.array([(v1-vp)/r1 + v1/r2 + i*(e**((v1-v2)/vt)-1), (vp-v2)/r3 -    v2/r4 + i*(e**((v1-v2)/vt)-1)])
    print y
    return y

def gradf(x):
'''
n-Derivative of f(x) where x is a vector of n-dimensions
'''
    v1, v2 = x[0], x[1]
    m = np.array([[1./r1 + 1./r2 + (i/vt)*e**((v1-v2)/vt), (i/vt)*e**((v1-v2)/vt)],\
    [(-i/vt)*e**((v1-v2)/vt), -1*(1./r3 +1./r4 +(i/vt)*e**((v1-v2)/vt))]], dtype = np.float64)#the matrix for the 'grad' f function
    print m
    return m

def cls_newton(x):
'''
Classroom implementation of the newton raphson method
'''
    v1, v2 = x[0], x[1]
    f_v1 = 1./r1 + 1./r2 + (i/vt)*e**((v1-v2)/vt)
    f_v2 = (-i/vt)*e**((v1-v2)/vt)
    g_v1 = (i/vt)*e**((v1-v2)/vt)
    g_v2 = -1*(1./r3 +1./r4 +(i/vt)*e**((v1-v2)/vt))

    f = (v1-vp)/r1 + v1/r2 + i*(e**((v1-v2)/vt)-1)
    g = (vp-v2)/r3 - v2/r4 + i*(e**((v1-v2)/vt)-1)

    print f
    print g
    print f_v2, g_v1, g_v1, f_v1  
    v1n = v1 - (f*g_v2 - g*f_v2)/(f_v1*g_v2 - g_v1*f_v2)
    v2n = v2 - (g*f_v1 - f*g_v1)/(f_v1*g_v2 - g_v1*f_v2)
    print v1n
    print v2n
    return np.array([v1n,v2n])

x1 = np.array([4., 5.]) #initial guess of roots are 4. and 5. volts
error = 1e-6 # permissible error
i = 0 # iteration counter

while norm(x1)>error and i < 50:
    delta = solve(gradf(x1), f(x1))
    x2 = x1 - delta
    print x2
    print 'x1 = {0}, x2 = {1}'.format(x1, x2)# test line
    x1 = x2
    print x1
    i+=1 

rt = x1 # estimated root of the equation

print 'The root of the equation is ' + str(rt) + '\n' + 'f(root) = ' +   str(f(rt))
print 'No. of iterations: ' + str(i)
```

In this code I've written functions for two different implementations of the method for multiple roots.

The one which I've used in this program is one where I solve an equation between  **gradf(x)** (Which produces a ***Jacobian matrix***) and **f(x**) (Which gives me the a vector with the equations which I found using Kirchoff's laws).

it works like **gradf(x).delta = f(x)**
so we find delta using the solve() function
and we subtract delta from x1 (our initial v1 and v2) to find x2

I'm having a problem with the matrix though, when I call the function gradf([4.,5.]) in Ipython, it gives me a matrix like

```
array([[  1.25000004e+00,   4.12230724e-08],
   [ -4.12230724e-08,  -8.33333375e-01]])
```

but the same matrix when printed during the normal operation of the program is something like

```
[[ 1.25        0.        ]
[ 0.         -0.83333333]]
```

I get this matrix in my first iteration regardless of the initial guess of v1 and v2 (or x1). The next iteration gives me an error like

```
LinAlgError: Singular matrix .
```

I don't think this is due to rounding off in Python either because when I individually print the value of (say) the first array element in the matrix (while running the script), it gives me a zero where it should be giving something like 4.12230724e-08.

**The classroom implementation** or cls_newton(x) which simplifies the equations before-hand and directly gives me x2 seems to do the same thing but I can't tell why, it gives me a different answer through Ipython and a different one during execution.

**Also, when I write say f_v1 I'm referring to the partial derivative of f with respect to v1 and g_v2 would be the partial derivative of g with respect to v2 and so on.**

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: How about printing the entire array before the `LinAlgError`? A single element won't tell you much about the determinant, which tells you if the matrix is singular.

Comment: I did do that. [[  4.70770534e+18   4.70770534e+18]
 [ -4.70770534e+18  -4.70770534e+18]] was the matrix before it gave me before the error for this version of my code. But the issue seems to stem from the matrix I get the first iteration (the one I mentioned in the question) I get that regardless of what I pass as x1

Comment: Your first matrix is irreproachable. The second one looks very wrong, probably because of the values of v where you evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really late response. If you're still interested in getting the answer, I think this code should do the trick. It gave me the correct answer for the last part to the question. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import numpy as np

Vp = 5 #V
R1 = 1e3 # ohms
R2 = 4e3 # ohms
R3 = 3e3 # ohms
R4 = 2e3 # ohms
I0 = 3e-9 # A
VT = 0.05 # V

tol = 1e-6

def f1(V):
    v1 = V[0]; v2 = V[1]
    return( (v1-Vp)/R1 + v1/R2 + I0*(np.exp((v1-v2)/VT)-1) )

def f2(V):
    v1 = V[0]; v2 = V[1]
    return( -(v2-Vp)/R3 - v2/R4 + I0*(np.exp((v1-v2)/VT)-1) )

def j11(V):
    v1 = V[0]; v2 = V[1]
    return 1/R1 + 1/R2 + I0/VT * np.exp((v1-v2)/VT)

def j12(V):
    v1 = V[0]; v2 = V[1]
    return -I0/VT * np.exp((v1-v2)/VT)

def j21(V):
    v1 = V[0]; v2 = V[1]
    return I0/VT * np.exp((v1-v2)/VT)

def j22(V):
    v1 = V[0]; v2 = V[1]
    return -1/R3 - 1/R4 - I0/VT * np.exp((v1-v2)/VT)

# initial guesses
v1 = 0.5
v2 = 0.5

V = np.array( [v1,v2] )
F = np.array( [ f1( V ) , f2( V ) ] )
J = np.array( [ [ j11( V ) , j12( V ) ] , [ j21( V ) , j22( V )] ] )
DV = np.dot( np.linalg.inv(J) , F )
estimate = V - DV
err = np.abs(estimate - V)
while ( err > tol ).any():
    F = np.array( [ f1(estimate) , f2(estimate) ] )
    J = np.array( [ [ j11(estimate) , j12(estimate) ] , [ j21(estimate) , j22(estimate) ] ] )
    DV = np.dot( np.linalg.inv(J) , F ) # f(x)/f'(x)
    new_estimate = estimate - DV
    err = np.abs(new_estimate - estimate)
    estimate = new_estimate

print("V1={:.4E}V\tV2={:.4E}V".format(*new_estimate))
print("Voltage across forward biased diode: {:.4E}V".format(new_estimate[0]-new_estimate[1]))
```